# Error when upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

Currently, I use Ubuntu 14.04. I have finally decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. But when I try to do so, I run into an error.

First, I run the Software Updater, which prompts me the following message:
[image]

After clicking Install, I get the following message:
[image]

When I start the Software Updater from within the console, I get the following exception message:

```
sudo update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 483, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(excep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 92, in commit
    _("Installing updates…"), True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 483, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(excep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 159, in _show_transaction
    yield trans.run()
aptdaemon.errors.TransactionFailed: Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty2) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty2 is to be installed
                            Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                            Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty2) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty2 is to be installed
                                 Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                                 Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-lts-xenial: Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial (>= 2:1.17.2-2) but 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.3~trusty2 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

If this can reassure you, the problem doesn't seem to come from your upgrade, rather from a very recent update. I'm on the 16.04 LTS since a couple weeks now, and I didn't encounter any problem like this. However, yesterday in the evening, I tried to do an update (which I didn't do for about a week or so), and this showed up:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Correction des dépendances... a échoué.
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Dépend: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.83-3~x~padoka0) mais 2.4.82+git20170807.ceb70a6b-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 est installé
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Dépend: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.83-3~x~padoka0) mais 2.4.82+git20170807.ceb70a6b-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 est installé
E: Erreur, pkgProblem::Resolve a généré des ruptures, ce qui a pu être causé par les paquets devant être gardés en l'état.
E: Impossible de corriger les dépendances
```

So even though this is in French (I'm sorry by the way), you can see it's quite the same error message.

After a few searches, it seems to be a problem with repository (e.g. an added repository conflicting with one of the official ones). Even though it didn't work for me, I give you this tip hoping it'll help: Go to "software and updates", in the first tab, make sure only "main" and "universe" are checked, and in the second tab, uncheck all third party repositories. Close the window and it might work. If it doesn't, well ... at least I'm not alone in this problem.